# Cannot parse Mozilla repo URL in SVN client. Trying to pull code

Tags: svn, repository, geckodriver

I want to try building the gecko driver from source.  The code is located in Mozilla repo here: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/testing/geckodriver

I downloaded tortoise svn and tried to use this URL and also the root URL in the SVN browser but it cannot parse it.

I am not familiar with SVN.  What is the correct way for me to pull the code locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [Mercurial (hg)](https://www.mercurial-scm.org) repository, not Subversion (SVN). TortoiseSVN is a Subversion client and does not support Mercurial.

You need to use a Mercurial client with this repository. Try [TortoiseHg](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io).